# Modeling of the aerodynamic characteristics of the wing

Tags: aerodynamics, wing, fluid-dynamics

As a part of the engineering thesis I work on the methods of modeling of aerodynamic characteristics of wing. In it, I rise an issue related to the impact of changes of aircraft attitude during maneuvers, I mean when there are angular rates like roll and yaw rate.

Now I'm looking for the methods which will be able to describe the spanwise change of lift and drag coefficiens during such maneuvers from the simplest ones to most advanced. So far I have considered so-called strip theory (when wing is discretized into independent strips and e.g. during positive roll rate there is increase of AoA along right wing and decrase on left one, so it causes appropriate change of lift, induced drag and profile drag) and Vortex Lattice Method. I know that in VLM I have to add aircraft angulara velocity because basic describtion of this method take into account just freestrem velocity caused by aircraft translation. I also think to analyse CFD method to estime wing characteristics in motion.

Hence my question, are there maybe other methods which estimate/model wing aerodynamic characteristics that I can consider? If there are methods which also describe the spanwise stall situation , I would be very grateful? Would you recomend any literature or articles related to above problem.

Comment: May be of interest [A review of aerodynamic flow models, solution methods and solvers](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid:d14b5f60-7000-439b-8785-62e513902bf8/datastream/OBJ1/download) from Delft TU, and the [High fidelity large eddy simulations](http://gdr-turbulence.ec-lyon.fr/Oct2012_Poitiers/Alferez-Gdr-turbulence-2012.pdf) from Onera.

Comment: The answer depends on what you have access to. The most capable software for modelling the moving airplane is proprietary and very expensive to acquire. On the other hand, vortex lattice methods already give good results within the realm of attached flow and should be accessible at your university.